# How to open modal with specific information in it

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a modal with information about the offer that is grabbed from the database.

**Here's what I have so far:** (Minimal required code)

---

*Opening modal:*

```
<a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoPonuka">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye spc"> </i>
</a>
```

*Modal:*

```
<div class="modal fade" id="infoPonuka" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="infoPonuka" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="infoPonuka">Ponuka - info:</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
            @if(isset($_GET['id']))
                @foreach ($ponuky AS $item)
                    @if($item->ID == $_GET['id'])
                        @php
                            $ponuka = $item;
                        @endphp
                        {{Debug::printr($ponuka, false);}}
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Zatvoriť</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I was doing it, I thought I could maybe just use `$_GET` to get the ID of the offer, so I can have specific data from an array because every opening modal (the first code block) is shown on every item, so I wanted to make it unique for every button by maybe adding the `href="?id={{ $ponuka->ID }}"`. But I was unable to do so. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Bootstrap has documentation on [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use ajax request on click of your anchor tag instead of using these attributes `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoPonuka"`, and then, in response of your ajax request, set the data in the html of the modal as [Passing ajax response data to modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439230/passing-ajax-response-data-to-modal)
and then show the modal as:

```
$("#modalId").modal("show");
```

right after the line your data is set to modal html.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method in a Controller and a route:
This will retun a redered view.

```
public function getOffer($offer_id)
{
    $offer = Offer::where('id', $offer_id);
    $renderedOfferView = view('modal.offer', ['offer' => $offer)->render();
    return return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'renderedOfferView' => $renderedOfferView]);
}
```

In your blade:

```
<a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#infoPonuka" onclick="getOffer('{{ $ponuka->ID }}')">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye spc"> </i>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="infoPonuka" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="infoPonuka" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="infoPonuka">Ponuka - info:</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body" id="getOfferContent">
            <!-- use the getOfferContent id to fill with data -->
            </div>
           
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Zatvoriť</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

getOffer(id){
    $('#getOfferContent').html(''); // clear data
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/your-getOffer-route',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            $('#getOfferContent').html(response.renderedOfferView); // fill data
        },
        error: function( response ) {

        }
    });
}
```

Do not forgot to set: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your `layout.blade.php` into `<head>` tag